# How to return an ascii character in SDL (freepascal)

Tags: sdl, keyboard-events, freepascal, readkey

I want to read an ascii key from the keyboard using SDL under freepascal.  I don't care about the pressing of shift, ctrl, caps, etc--just things that would normally produce a character when typed in a typical application.

The problem is that I can't seem to detect KMOD_CAPS correctly.  If you press it multiple times, you end up with different results for the same CAPS state.

This is what I have so far:

```
program ReadKeySDL;
{SDL implementation of the crt readkey function.}

uses
    sdl;

const
    validkeys=[8,13,27,32..126];
    lowercase=[97..122];

var
    screen          :   pSDL_Surface;
    event           :   pSDL_Event;
    eventkey        :   tSDLKey;
    eventmod        :   tSDLMod;
    key             :   char;
    keyselected     :   boolean;


BEGIN


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen:=SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    if (screen=nil) then halt(1);

    new(event);
    repeat
        keyselected:=false;
        repeat
            if (SDL_WaitEvent(event) = 1) then
            begin
                if (event^.type_ = SDL_KeyDown) then
                begin
                    eventkey:=event^.key.keysym.sym;
                    eventmod:=event^.key.keysym.modifier;
                    writeln;
                    writeln('eventkey: ',eventkey);
                    writeln('eventmod: ',eventmod);
                    if (eventkey in validkeys) then
                    begin
                        keyselected:=true;
                        if ((eventkey in lowercase) and ((eventmod and (KMOD_CAPS or KMOD_SHIFT)) <> 0)) then
                            key:=chr(eventkey - 32)
                        else
                            key:=chr(eventkey);
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        until((keyselected) and (event^.type_ = SDL_KeyUp));
        writeln('Your key is: ',key,' (',ord(key),')');
        writeln('Final eventkey: ',eventkey);
        writeln('Final eventmod: ',eventmod);
    until(ord(key) = 27);
    dispose(event);


    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_Quit;

END.
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the unicode field in `key.keysym.unicode`. As long as you are reading characters (i.e. letters and numbers) it should translate quite nicely to ASCII.

Comment: That would be excellent, especially if it would handle capital letters and all the other character.  Right now I'm realizing with my method I'm going to be hard-coding the mapping of my particular keyboard... which isn't good.  I just need to find out how to translate unicode into ascii in freepascal.

Comment: Your comment seems to answer my problem!  A simple cast of the unicode works!

Comment: @opp Congrats, you could write a proper answer and get a +1.